# Can I stream into a ZipOutputStream (or similar) to archive multiple files *simultaneously* (Java)?

Tags: java, zip, archive, outputstream

I am writing an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) application. Its function is to take a large amount of data from a source (think many gigabytes), enrich/transform it and serve up in a *my-transformed-data.zip* archive containing both a "good" data file and a filtered out "bad" data file.

I have thus far used streaming methods to download from the source and perform the transformations, achieving a very low memory overhead. The issue is now archiving those two files together in a streaming fashion to be passed onto the client.

Investigated options:

1. A ZipOutputStream (with multiple putNextEntry of ZipEntry) would work perfectly if I could stream all of the good data first, then the bad data after but this is not the case and sorting the source to that format would require a large memory/storage overhead which I definitely want to avoid.
2. Java 7 brought with it the NIO package that I think offers some of the sort of functionality I require ([e.g writing to the archive simultaneously](http://www.pixeldonor.com/2013/oct/12/concurrent-zip-compression-java-nio/)) but it cannot see a way to have that file be piped over a stream rather than written to disk.

So is there a way that I can have multiple OutputStreams piped through a ZipOutputStream (or similar) such that I maintain my low memory/storage usage and get a zipped file with two (or better N) files inside it?

My general knowledge on archiving and filesystems is fairly junior, so any tangential advice is very much welcome.

Comment: ZIP is not designed for multiplexing.  Can you save the smallest entry of the two on disk until the other one is done?

Comment: Ah, this is the kind of fundamental blocker I was interested in uncovering. Zip just isn't designed for this kind of process? Saving to disk as you describe is an undesirable option but if there is no alternative it's what I am doing currently. My hope is/was there would be some alternative steaming based solution - even if it's a little hacky.

Comment: No.  One entry at a time in a ZIP file.  You might have better luck with constructing a filesystem image on the fly.  I am not aware of any such implementations though.

Comment: Can't you do the processing on the server providing the data - this is normally why we use SQL with databases.

Comment: What do you mean by "constructing a filesystem image on the fly"? Also, are there any other archiving formats that would enable multiplexing that you are aware of? I'm not picky on it being a .zip.

Transforming on the source server/db is doable but not so nice - the "transform" step involves reaching out to a few other systems for enriching the data. Though that is something I could consider, thank you. I think for now I will just depend on writing the "bad" data to local storage since there is less of it but the problem will grow as this system gets more traffic.

Comment: That you generate the bytes in your code that when downloaded on the target computer would correspond to a valid filesystem-in-a-file (like ISO or DMG) as they are typically block devices.  I do not know of any implementations of such a construct as most people typically do that transformation in the upstream database query allowing the ETL to not hold state.